# Keeping aspect ratio of swfObject DOM element

Tags: html, css, flash, aspect-ratio

Is there a way to keep the aspect ratio in a responsive flash swfObject?

An swfObject automatically sizes the stage to fit the screen if the screen is smaller than the DOM element. This can cause some visual issue if a messy flash file has elements that should not be visible outside the stage([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/ejbLp/15/)).
To avert this, I am passing an a parameter scale with the value exactfit.([read more here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html))

However now the flash will loose it's aspect ratio and become distorted. If the dom element would keep the ratio the flash would not distort.

Is there a way to make the object element keep its aspect ratio within the dom. CSS solutions would be nice!

Here is a fiddle of how it is now, (notice it is horizontally and vertically aligned and should stay that way):

http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/ejbLp/13/

HTML

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="helper1"></div>
    <div class="helper">
        <object class="swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://philipp.werminghausen.us/testing/twincle_test3.swf" id="replace" style="visibility: visible;">
            <param name="usemap" value="#maptest">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <param name="scale" value="exactfit">
        </object>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.helper1 {
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:-240px;
    min-height: 240px;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.helper {
    max-width: 550px;
    max-height: 480px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.swf {
    max-width: 550px;
    max-height: 480px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Try using vh and vw. I played a bit and achieved the keep of the aspect ratio. Here's what it is http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/length.html and here's the browser support http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: This looks interesting, but I have to support IE8+

Comment: I was curious anyways, I implemented it and it works, with a couple of new bugs introduced having to do with the alignment. but the ratio is fixed! I wish this was compatible with IE8.this is how it looks:http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/ejbLp/18/

Comment: I believe that's the easiest way. Others involve using JS/jQuery. [offtopic] Do not support IE8. Supporting old-browsers is an atavism, now the browsers is a full-stack software programm and keeping it up to date is the user's responsibility. Like, for example, update of all other programms - FileZilla, Sublime, Atom, or Game Patches. Wanna use new features - make users install new software [/offtopic]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a choice regarding IE8. I am thinking of using this anyways and making a js fallback solution for unsupported browsers. I managed to clean up some more bugs: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/ejbLp/23/ The only issue remaining is that it is still looking it's aspect ratio when the width or height is tiny. Any Ideas on this?

Comment: I was just testing the new link cross-browser, it only seems to work in chrome so never mind on that.